# Raycasting to determine point inside or outside mesh, edge case?

Tags: raycasting, 3d-meshes

I'm trying to determine if a point is inside or outside a (triangle) mesh.
The best way I found was to cast a ray from the point and count how many triangles intersect. (Odd or even).

I used Möller–Trumbore algo to check the ray/triangle-intersection.

But I now have a situation where point is outside the cube. But it touches the side. So the ray intersects the triangle, but doesn't go inside the cube. So I get only 1 intersection with a triangle. What normally means, it is inside the cube. What is definitely wrong.

Interactive example of the case (white triangles does not intersect, yellow triangles intersect, intersection and start point in red. And also the ray in red):
https://coffee-wrennie-15.tiiny.site/

Are there ways to distinguish cases that just brush the mesh? Or are there more robust algorithms?

Just to be complete, the code

```
private boolean isInsideInner2(VectorMM point) {
    VectorMM direction = createSafeRay(); // Create ray that isn't parallel with any triangle
    HashSet<VectorMM> uniques = new HashSet<>();

    for(int i = 0; i!= triangles.length ; i++) {  
        VectorMM intersect = rayIntersectsTriangle2(point, direction, triangles[i]);
        
        if(intersect == point) {
            return true;
        }
        if(intersect != null) {
            uniques.add(intersect);
        }
    }

    return (uniques.size() % 2) == 1 ? true : false;
}

private static VectorMM rayIntersectsTriangle2(VectorMM rayOrigin, 
                                            VectorMM rayVector,
                                            VectorMM[] triangle) {
    // source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm

    VectorMM vertex0 = triangle[0];
    VectorMM vertex1 = triangle[1];
    VectorMM vertex2 = triangle[2];
    VectorMM edge1 = VectorMM.sub(vertex1, vertex0);
    VectorMM edge2 = VectorMM.sub(vertex2, vertex0);
    VectorMMLong h = VectorMM.crossproductPrecise(rayVector, edge2);

    double a = VectorMMLong.dot(edge1, h);
    if (a > -EPSILON && a < EPSILON) {
        throw new AssertionError("Should not happen as we removed all parallell rays by creating the rayVector"); 
    }

    double f = 1.0 / a;
    VectorMM s = VectorMM.sub(rayOrigin, vertex0);
    double u = f * (VectorMMLong.dot(s,h));
    if (u < -EPSILON || u > 1.0+EPSILON) {
        return null;
    }
    VectorMMLong q = VectorMM.crossproductPrecise(s, edge1);
    double v = f * VectorMMLong.dot(rayVector, q);
    if (v < -EPSILON || u + v > 1.0+EPSILON) {
        return null;
    }
    
    double t = f * VectorMMLong.dot(edge2, q);

    if(t >= 0) {
        if(t == 0) {
            return rayOrigin;
        }

        return VectorMM.add(rayOrigin, VectorMM.mul(rayVector, t));
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: So, the case in which the algorithm fails is when the ray is "tangential" to a triangle?

Comment: So when the ray is exactly crossing through one of the edge. Then it is possible that it is a ray from inside to outside. Or just a ray 'brushing' the edge without changing the side...

Comment: Ah, I see now what the problem is, sorry. Are the vertices of the triangle ordered to implicitly represent orientation? (see [this explanation](https://knowww.eu/nodes/59b8e93cd54a862e9d7e40c8)) If so, you could use the dot product of the normal and the ray direction to figure out whether you are hitting the outside or the inside. If everything is correct, you should always hit the same number of insides and outsides. If the number is not the same, you are in one of these cases.

Comment: See [Point_in_polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) - Limited precision.

Comment: Thanks for information. Am I correct that the winding number calculation in the "Point in polygon" link is the same as what PepeOjeda is describing? Or do you have some implementation in 3D? As I'm not totally confident I could transform the 2D algorithm into 3D.

Comment: No, that "winding number" is a different thing. The thing that @Mangata links should also be good for identifying these problem cases (you could use the [itersection-point-to-edge distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment) with a threshold to figure out if you are close enough to an edge for numerical precision to become a problem). I guess both that method and the normal calculation still leave the question of what to do once you have identified that you are dealling with a problem case (maybe move the ray?)